# Spring boot actuator gauge provides unreliable data

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul, spring-boot-actuator, gauge

I don't understand what this value intends to provide.

According to the documentation, the gauge sounds like the "totals" while the counter is the delta (since last request? delta compared to what?).

Well, in my standard spring boot application (still on version 1.4.2), all counters are 0 and the gauge would go up and down without any logic.

I am the only person in the system, i'll hit refresh, and i'll get a value like this:

```
{"gauge.servo.response.rest.star-star":20.0}
```

I'll hit refresh again on the application, and i'll get this again:

```
{"gauge.servo.response.rest.star-star":20.0}
```

Hit refresh again, and I get this:

```
{"gauge.servo.response.rest.star-star":12.0}
```

How can this number ever go DOWN? shouldn't it always increase as the use on my system increases? Perhaps it gauges the last few seconds? If so, how do I know when to monitor?

I need a decent monitoring solution that provides the following data:

- Total number of requests (and rate)
- Total number of errors
- Latency information

Seems like item #3 is not supported by metrics at all, and the first two simply don't work as I expect them to.

Note: this server is a Spring Zuul gateway, but I don't think this should impact anything?

Any help would be appreciated.